# How to create a new column where the values come from a number minus a column?

Tags: r, dataframe

My goal is to create a new column "Yi1" that is 52 in the first row, then 52 minus "di1" from row 1 would follow in row 2, then the "Yi1" value in row 2 minus the "di1" in row 2 would be in row 3 and so on.

The result should look like below:

```
    time di1 Yi1
1     1   1   52   
2     3   2   51
3     4   1   49
4     5   0   48
5     8   0   48
6    10   1   48
7    12   0   47
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do

```
df1$Yi1 <- c(52, head(52 - cumsum(df1$di1), -1))
df1$Yi1  
#[1] 52 51 49 48 48 48 47
```

Or slightly shorter

```
with(df1, c(52, 52 - cumsum(di1[-length(di1)])))
#[1] 52 51 49 48 48 48 47
```

Or wth `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(Yi1  = lag(52 - cumsum(di1), default = 52) )
#  time di1 Yi1
#1    1   1  52
#2    3   2  51
#3    4   1  49
#4    5   0  48
#5    8   0  48
#6   10   1  48
#7   12   0  47
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(time = c(1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 8L, 10L, 12L), di1 = c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6", "7"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Ok thanks! what would I do if I only want this to be done to row 1-21 of df1, and leave the remaining rows 22-39(will fill in other numbers).

Comment: @TongClaireXu can you please update your post wiith a new example as it is not clear about the values it change

Comment: @TongClaireXu not clear, perhaps `unsplit(Map(function(x, y) c(y, head(y - cumsum(x$di1),-1)), split(df1,  seq_len(nrow(df1)) < 21), c(52, 44)), seq_len(nrow(df1)) < 21)`